# Unit Testing using MOQ: test if a method is called on certain conditions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I have a method which internally calls methodB but based on certain condition

```
methodA(Req req)
{
if(req.Quantity > 10)
{
_someIinterface.methodB(req);
}
}
```

and I have mutiple conditions where

quantity=1 -> methodB() wont be executed

quantity=5 -> methodB() wont be executed

quantity=11 -> methodB() will be executed

quantity=4 -> methodB() wont be executed

SO I have a test case like

```
[Theory]
[JsonFileData("TestData.json", "ScenarioRequest")]
public void TestMethodB()
{
Mock<SomeInterface> moq= new Mock<SomeInterface>();
moq.Setup(x=>x.methodB(It.IsAny<Req>())).Verifiable();
sut.methodA(req);
moq.Verify(x=>x.methodB(It.IsAny<Req>()),Times.Once());

}
```

source of JsonFileData is from 
https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-custom-xunit-theory-test-dataattribute-to-load-data-from-json-files/

So in this case the testcase 1 and 2 fail but testcase 3,4 passes even though testcase 4 has quantity 4.
Does anyone know how to test such cases?

Comment: Please post your complete methodA. In your methodA you have condition that `if(req.Quantity > 10)` then execute `_interface.methodB(req);` but you are saying that `quantity=11 -> methodB() wont be executed`

Comment: I just updated the question. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: You are always checking if your MethodB is executed or not even for `req.Quantity` less than 10